# Node Js ES6 - Recursive function call - Wrong possible loop detection "TypeError: this.elem.method is not a function"

Tags: node.js, loops, recursion, detection

Having a recursive code, Node Js procesor detect we could have a bucle and block execution giving a wrong error code.

We can reproduce this case with a simple inheritance classes example :

```
class A()
constructor()
{
this.b1 = new B()
}

class B()
{
// Here we could to have a loop ( recursive inheritance ) 
...
this.a1 = new A()
...
}
```

Of course we could to change this code with an exit condition so never will enter in a real loop, but node Js processor only review stack class status.

A possible solution could be to have different A, B classes to avoid inheritance repeat class names, but I think is a wrong solution.

This problem happen if we have classes on different files.

Anybody would know an alternate solution for node ?

Here Complete example to you be able to reproduce directly. Now the error message is not the same than in my real case but too breaks execution.

a.es6 file :

```
const   { B }           =   require('/brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa/b.es6' );


class A {

    constructor(n = 0) 
    {
        this.n  =   'My Class_name Is A'

        console.log(this.n + ' and Level ' + n)

        if (n > 0 )
            this.b1 =   new B(n)

    }
}

var a1 = new A(3)


exports.A = A
```

b.es6 file :

```
const   { A }           =   require('/brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa/a.es6' );


class B {
    constructor(n = 0)
    {
        this.n  =   'My Class_name Is B'
        this.a1 = ''

        console.log(this.n + ' and Level ' + n)

        if (n > 0) 
            this.a1 = new A(n - 1)

    }
}

exports.B = B
```

Node results :

/

```
brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa>node a.es6 
My Class_name Is A and Level 3
My Class_name Is B and Level 3
/mnt/ssd/brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa/b.es6:16
            this.a1 = new A(n - 1)
                      ^

TypeError: A is not a constructor
    at new B (/mnt/ssd/brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa/b.es6:16:16)
    at new A (/mnt/ssd/brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa/a.es6:16:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/ssd/brqx/base/rcode/es6/spc/theme/common/yamls/sections/sa/a.es6:21:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
```

Regards.

Ricardo.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish with this, the basic rules of recursion apply.  You need to have a 'base case' that breaks recursion at some point.  Node is no different.

Comment: Be sure I have base case. I'm very good in recursive skills. I didn't put real example to avoid to have a lot of lines. so please check with case base what could be a simple string or integer comparation and you will see node break execution with same message.

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle would help?